# Why is a pointer to int initialised with “*int” and not “&int”?

Tags: pointers, go, reference, memory-address, dereference

For example, when initialising a pointer to an int, we use:

```
var pointer *int
```

Why is the syntax not instead:

```
var pointer &int
```

To me, the second version would have made more sense as it would read like “variable ‘pointer’ is a memory address of an int”

Or to put it another way, I find it confusing that the “*” is used for both for defining a memory address type (as above), and for dereferencing, e.g.
*pointer = 123

Is this as confusing as it seems, or am I missing something here?

Comment: That's C's heritage.

Comment: One might as well ask why function definition uses `func` instead of `def`, or why Go has `float32` and `float64` instead of `float` and `double`, or any number of similar questions. The people who defined it picked those names, operator spellings, etc., at that time because they liked them then (and maybe still do now).

Comment: @torek, sometimes knowing the reasoning behind syntax can be helpful in understanding its function or intended purpose.

Comment: With your example, it’s helpful to know that float32 or float64 refers to the bits of precision

Comment: I have completed the answer.

Comment: `To me, the second version would have made more sense as it would read like “variable ‘pointer’ is a memory address of an int”` this is opinion based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` is an [address operator](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), not a type.

> For an operand `x` of type `T`, the **address operation** `&x` generates a pointer of type `*T` to `x`.

But it is true `*` is also used as a **pointer indirection**:

> For an operand `x` of pointer type `*T`, the **pointer indirection `*x`** denotes the variable of type `T` pointed to by `x`

As seen in [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1), `*` references both a type and an operator.

This [thread from 2016](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/golang-nuts/%22address$20operator%22%7Csort:date/golang-nuts/zYcZUq6KJFQ/siXWZwOuAwAJ) asks a similar question.

> The pointer syntax is just copied from C, of course.
>   See also [**Go's Declaration Syntax**](https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax)
>   If we had used '`&`', then a Go pointer would look like a C++ reference.

And:

> `*int` defines a pointer type and then can be used with or without the `*` on the variable.
>
> - With the `*` you access the value pointed to.
> - Without, you access the memory address pointed to.
>
> `&` retrieves a memory address from a variable.
>
> An address is not a pointer and vice versa.
>   You define a pointer using a memory address.
>
> ```
> var x int = 10    // declare an int variable `x` holding the value 10.
> var y *int = &x  // Create a pointer `y` *using* the memory address of `x`.
> ```
>
> `*y` will have the value 10.
>   `y` will be the memory address of `x`

---

See more in "[**Pointers in Go**](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/17/pointers-in-go)" from **[Dave Cheney](https://twitter.com/davecheney)**:

> Go pointers, like C pointers, are values that, uh, point to other values. This is a tremendously important concept and shouldn’t be considered dangerous or something to get hung up on.
>
> [A pointer is a value that points to the memory address of another variable](https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/26/understand-go-pointers-in-less-than-800-words-or-your-money-back).

But:

> you cannot alter the address p points to unless you assign another address to it
>   No: `var p *int; p++` possible.

(See also "[Go at Google: Language Design in the Service of Software Engineering](https://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article#TOC_12.)")

> Once a value is assigned to a pointer, with the exception of nil, Go guarantees that the thing being pointed to will continue to be valid for the lifetime of the pointer.

Comment: Excellent answer. I find a full example helps clarify pointer types for me https://play.golang.org/p/JVUgWDcC7TT. The other option is don't use them if you don't have to. See https://play.golang.org/p/2mqXouLaHDZ.

Comment: @TomJ Good point. Thank you for those examples.